# Updates failing trust validation on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, certificate

Windows Update is giving me this error:

> We couldn't install updates because there's a problem with the date and time information on your device. Make sure your date, time, and time zone settings are correct and we'll try again later.

My date and time settings are correct. I found a [blog post](http://nerdsknowbest.blogspot.com/2017/01/Windows-10-2016-Update-Date-Time-0x800B0101.html) suggesting that it could be a problem with WSUS. My organization does have a WSUS server, but the admin assures me that its certificates are up to date and its time settings are also correct.

The messages in my Windows Update error log led me to a [TechNet Q&A](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/8a0af1a8-eb63-4719-a2a0-1b466cd3a09c/patches-failing-error-verifying-trust?forum=configmgrgeneral) from five years ago that seems to describe exactly the same problem. My log is basically identical to the one reported there:

```
Validating signature for C:\[path omitted]\Windows10.0-KB4022730-X64.cab with dwProvFlags 0x00000080:
Error: 0x800b0101 when verifying trust for C:\[path omitted]\Windows10.0-KB4022730-X64.cab
Digital Signatures on file C:\[path omitted]\Windows10.0-KB4022730-X64.cab are not trusted: Error 0x800b0101
```

The accepted answer on that Q&A made no difference, and I'm not sure how to apply the other answers to Windows 10.

**What is the solution to this problem on Windows 10?**

Comment: S0 your PC is on a domain? We cannot help with domain controlled pc's here unfortunately.

Comment: Sounds like the certificate used to sign that .cab file isn’t trusted for whatever reason. Only your Administrators can fix your issue

Comment: @Ramhound Only my machine is affected. Does this point to my certificates being corrupted? I suppose the only fix is to wipe and reinstall.